# D-Bus equivalent for Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, ipc, dbus

Anyone know of a Linux/D-Bus sort of mechanism for Windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Choose your poison:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx

> The following IPC mechanisms are
>   supported by Windows:
>
> - Clipboard
> - COM
> - Data Copy
> - DDE
> - File Mapping
> - Mailslots
> - Pipes
> - RPC
> - Windows Sockets

The closest to DBus is COM.

Comment: Will windows apps ever standardise on a single RPC/MQ system?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai COM has been the defacto standard as long as I can remember.

Answer (score 31):

The [reference D-Bus implementation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) natively supports Windows.  Previously, [the WinDBus project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windbus/) could be used.  There is no need for equivalents if you want to use D-Bus.

Comment: Does it really support well enough to be used for production software? The link in your answer states "a port to Windows is in progress." (as of 2020/02/20)

Comment: They are making progress! Today on the same link I can read: `the port to Windows is mostly finished.`

Answer (score 9):

windbus is now part of the official DBus releases, see: 
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/#windowsport