# Implementing message bus like DBus on Windows

Tags: python, windows, signals-slots, dbus

I used DBus for emitting signal from one component for other on Linux. I needed to port code for Windows. How I can emit signal in one component and receive it on two other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DBus equivalent for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482681/dbus-equivalent-for-windows)

Comment: [*the official reference implementation has Windows support*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2029585/95735)